How to make table cell height equal without image on one cell overgrow the table?
So I have a <table> that has 1 row with 2 columns, one row containing an extraordinarily large image, the other row just contains your usual table cell content - a few <p>s.
Here's a sample:


td {
  background-color: RebeccaPurple;
  padding: 0;
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/500"></td>
    <td><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>



When the image is larger than the 2nd table cell, the whole table grows. I want the image to have a height which makes both of the cells equal height. Is this possible without setting a fixed height for the table?

What do you mean by making both cells equal height? Right now, the cells are the same height, the table just gets bigger to accommodate the image.

Are you using <table> for layout purpose?

What about the image width, aspect ratio?

We will set the width and height of the image but maintaining its aspect ratio allowing any image to fit nicely into the box


<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 50%; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="Example Image" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; object-fit: cover;" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
      <p>hhhh placeholder` hhhh</p>
      <p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p>
      <p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p>
      <p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>




You can achieve the said result by setting a height of image instead of table.


td {
  background-color: RebeccaPurple;
  padding: 0;
}

td img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://picsum.photos/500"></td>
    <td><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>






<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 50%;">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" alt="Example Image" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" />
    </td>
    <td style="width: 50%; text-align: center;">
      <p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p><p>hhhh placeholder hhhh</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>




You made the table equal width while I'm asking for equal height. Sorry! ._.
